# Calculation of Drag coefficient for infinite cylinder

Tags: fluid-dynamics, drag, flow

I would like to calculate the drag coefficient for an infinite cylinder for various Reynolds numbers.

I'm using $C_D=\large{\frac F{\frac 12Av^2\rho}}$

My question is how do I calculate force ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can either measure $F$ and $v$ then calculate $C_D$ from the eqn, or you can look up $C_D$ in a table for the corresponding Reynolds number [1], and use that to calculate $F$.  You cannot calculate both quantities using one equation.

[1] http://www.thermopedia.com/content/707/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it possible to find the force from pressure gradients across the cross sectional area ? like F= P.A, with P as pressure difference from inflow and outflow?

Comment: I think not.  The pressure will vary at different points around the cylinder, especially if flow is turbulent - so where will you measure pressure difference?  If you measure far enough up- and down-stream there will be no pressure difference at all.  Moreover, if drag depended only on pressure difference and XSA then it would be the same for all objects with the same XSA and pressure difference - drag coefficient would then be the same in all cases.

Answer (score -1):

No matter how slight the aerodynamic pressure, your force is infinite, because the cylinder is infinite.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/377023)